# Question about an equality

Tags: calculus

Is this equality correct

$$ \frac{       0 + A \varepsilon e^{-a \varepsilon} + A 2 \varepsilon e^{-a2 \varepsilon}  + \dots         }{ A + A e^{-a\varepsilon} +  A e^{-a2\varepsilon} + \dots } = \frac{\varepsilon}{e^{-a\varepsilon} - 1}, $$

where $A$ and $a$ are constants and $\varepsilon$ is some small number? It seems to me that there should be no minus in the exponent on the r.h.s.

EDITS: Edits were made to correct the third term in the denominator and to add a negative sign in the exponents.

REMARK: This question was answered very well by @dxiv, so I don't understand why it's closed. @dxiv's answer was very helpful, indeed, and that can be useful for other readers of this site as well.

Comment: Why edit the question since it has already been answered, very well, at that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  simplify $A$ between the numerator and denominator, and let $e^{-a \varepsilon}=b\,$ then the LHS is:

$$ \frac{\varepsilon \,( b + 2 b^{2}  + \dots)}{ 1 + b + b^{2} + \dots }$$

For $\,|b| \lt 1 \iff a \varepsilon \gt 0\,$ the series converge $\displaystyle\sum_{n \ge 0} n b^n = \frac{b}{(1-b)^2}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n \ge 0} b^n = \frac{1}{1-b}$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   To sum up the comments, the above gives:

$$
\frac{       0 + A \varepsilon e^{-a \varepsilon} + A 2 \varepsilon e^{-a2 \varepsilon}  + \dots         }{ A + A e^{-a\varepsilon} +  A e^{-a2\varepsilon} + \dots } = \frac{\varepsilon \,( b + 2 b^{2}  + \dots)}{ 1 + b + b^{2} + \dots } = \frac{\varepsilon \,b}{1-b} = \frac{\varepsilon}{\cfrac{1}{b}-1} = \frac{\varepsilon}{e^{a \varepsilon}-1}
$$

This differs from the posted RHS of $\;\displaystyle\frac{\varepsilon}{e^{\color{red}{\mathbf{-}}a \varepsilon}-1}\;$ but that must have been a typo in the source text, since with a negative exponent $\,e^{\color{red}{\mathbf{-}}a \varepsilon}-1 \lt 0\,$ while the LHS is always positive.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. I'll correct it in the OP.

Comment: all constants are positive but I saw other typos which I'l correct in the OP.

Comment: @ganzewoort Updated my answer accordingly. Also, I guess that should be $\,e^{\color{red}{\mathbb{+}}a \varepsilon}-1\,$ on the RHS.

Comment: The English translation clearly shows a minus there but I guess it's a typo. If it's plus do we also get in the denominator (1 - b)?

Comment: @ganzewoort If it's a minus then $\,e^{\color{red}{\mathbf{-}}a\varepsilon}-1 \lt 0\,$ for $\,a \varepsilon \gt 0\,$, so the RHS would be negative, while the LHS is obviously positive. So, yes, I would assume that's a typo. As for the denominator, the ratio of the two sums above is $\displaystyle\frac{b}{(1-b)^2} \Big{/} \frac{1}{1-b} = \frac{b}{1-b}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{b}-1}= \frac{1}{e^{a \varepsilon}-1}\,$.

Comment: @ganzewoort `if b>1` Then both series *and* their ratio diverge. Btw, I see you changed the sign again in the question on the RHS. That can't be right, simply because the LHS is always positive while the RHS goes negative with this latest change.

Comment: I understand, but I wanted to keep the equality the way it was in the initial OP, reflecting what I saw in the literature. The typos on the l.h.s. were mine and I corrected them.

Comment: @ganzewoort Understood. I added a note at the end to cover that.

Comment: You answered the question very well, I upvoted your answer and accepted it. The algorithm of the site, however, put it on hold although there's nothing else to be added to it. Therefore, I want to delete the the question. Do you mind?

Comment: @ganzewoort I don't have a problem, that's your call entirely.